# Como pasar datos dinamicos a un web-component en angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5, angular6

tengo un proyecto en angular el cual interactura con un web component externo algo similar a esto

```
<external-webcomponent params='{

    "idUsuario": "667"

    }' >

</external-webcomponent>
```

pasa que no logro pasar el atributo params como una variable, solo me funciona con datos estaticos como en el ejemplo, en mi caso necesito cambiar el atrubuto params y enviarle un nuevo id al idUusuario, alguien sabe cual es la forma en la que se deben pasar los datos en ese caso?

logre pasarle los datos de forma dinamica de esta forma [attr.params]="getParametros()", sin embargo el componente realiza un llamado a una api y cuando le paso los datos de esa forma los params van vacios y cuando son estaticos si llevan valores, no se si es un problema con angular o un problema con el componente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

en el html:

```
<external-webcomponent [params]="'{ "idUsuario": "667" }'"></external-webcomponent>
```

en el typescript del componente **external-webcomponent** verificar si está incluido el Input y si es de tipo string o verificar de qué tipo es, dependiendo de eso, puedes crear un modelo o importar del componente.

```
@Input() params: string;
```